# compiled django application fails to run ASGI channels

Tags: django, pyinstaller

I'm building a django application using Pyinstaller.
When I run the application i get an error from dapne server.

"daphne\server.py:13: UserWarning: Something has already installed a non-asyncio Twisted reactor. Attempting to uninstall it; you can fix this warning by importing daphne.server early in your codebase or finding the package that imports Twisted and importing it later on."

In addition, when I compare the console log of the EXE application and a regular run of the django application I notice the following difference.
In the regular run which works as expected I see the following print:
"Django version 2.1.5, using settings 'cfehome.settings'
Starting ASGI/Channels version 2.1.5 development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/"

however, when I run the application from the EXE I see:
"Django version 2.1.5, using settings 'cfehome.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/"

Appreciate any lead to understand this behavior and ways to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but for others seeking answer. There's a simple fix:

Before importing raven in `settings.py`, `import daphne.server` So, your `settings.py` will look like this:

```
import daphne.server
import raven
```

For further information you can read: https://github.com/django/channels/issues/793

I hope it will help.